# How to implement a loading page in JSF 2.2

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to implement a **loading page** like gmail in my JSF web Application.

1. User enters login and password i take him to a simple page with progress bar **(loading Application Page**).
2. once the progress bar hits 100% the Application page is shown.

(hits 100% means that it gets progress value according to the progress of the initialization of the **Application page**).

Now, what do i really need to implement this, backing beans scopes, number of facelets, faces-config..

***Additional info :***

- i'm using `Primefaces 4.0`
- i'm using a WebFilter :

  @WebFilter(filterName = "AuthFilter", urlPatterns =
  {"*.xhtml"}) to redirect the not connecetd user to the login page.

[image]

---

This is what I've tried so far but no luck (the application stops in the loading page).

**login.xhtml** backing bean userBean(session scoped).

```
userBean.doLogin()  ==> return "loaderPage";
```

**loaderPage.xhtml** no backing bean

```
<h:body>
    <p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true"
                   value="#{dyna.progress}"
                   labelTemplate="{value}%"
                   styleClass="animated">  
        <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{userBean.onComplete}" />  
    </p:progressBar>  
</h:body>
```

dyna.progress <==this is located on the **Application page** backing bean (session scoped)

this is how i set the value on progress bar of **loadingPage.xhtml**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dyna", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        progress = 0;
        etatdateOptions = ListsMaker.getDateFilters();
        progress = 10;
        optionspatState = ListsMaker.getPatientStates();
        progress = 20;
        optionsCotpatState = ListsMaker.getPayementStates();
        progress = 30;
         ...}
```

This is the faces-config

```
<faces-config version="2.2"
          xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/loader.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{userBean.oncomplete}</from-action>
        <to-view-id>/AppPlace.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/AppPlace.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{dyna.killView}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
          <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
           <redirect>     
           </redirect>
       </navigation-case>
   </navigation-rule>
```

Comment: i thought its a clean and clear question though no one could answer.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to get JSF do the "progress" thing... I think you might need a client-side solution.. maybe like this http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/

Comment: I want to get the progress of the init method of the view scoped managed bean how would a client side solution help ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the solution Primefaces provides, namely [ProgressBar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/progressBar.jsf). In your case I would not make the `init()` method `@PostConstruct`, I would call the `init()` method once the client is forwarded to the `loaderPage.xhtml`. From there on you can call `getProgress()`.

Comment: You could do an update once the page has reached 100% which sets some `rendered` attribute for some component to true.